# How to affect verticies by modifiers depending on vertex group weights?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I want to be able to manipulate feature lines, so the geometry inbetween follows along. Here the simplest example, I can think of:
1 Grid with 2 vertex groups and crossed weights to each other
1 poly line on one side
1 poly line on the other
For what reason doesn't the geometry follow the second poly line?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am aware of the mesh and surface deform modifiers.
Both would work perfectly for this example. However, this is only a simple example. On more complicated geometry they have their limits.

[image]

Comment: In this case you better Project along the Z axis intead of useing the "Nearest Surface Point" in the Shrinkwrap modifer.